# Get attachments from E-mail

Tags: c#, file, filestream, mime, mime-message

I'm trying to get the attachments from a MimeMessage.

I got as far as this:

```
using (Stream ms = Utils.GenerateStreamFromString(mail.Rfc822Content))
{
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(ms);
    // collect our list of attachments
    foreach (MimeEntity attachment in mimeMessage.Attachments)
    {
        if (!fileexists)
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(docMap), bijlageNaam), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.CopyTo(file);
                file.Flush();
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

but the problem is, right now it obivously writes the fullContent because I'm using the `ms` to `.CopyTo(file)` which is not what I want.

I'm trying to get the attachments attached to the email and write those to a file.

Comment: What is `fileexists`? Get the filename from the mimeMessage and close it after writing it.

Comment: `fileexists` is simply a `boolean` that is checked using a filename to see if it doesn't already exist. cuz I only want to write new files.. I cut some code out to keep it focussed on the `mime` and not other things like `fileexists`

Comment: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeEntity_WriteTo_5.htm (i.e `attachment.WriteTo(file)`). Or http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeEntity_WriteTo_7.htm to avoid the need for `file` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by replacing the `foreach` with `using (var iter = new MimeIterator(mimeMessage))`

and started looping using a `while(item.MoveNext())`

thanks to that I had acces to the `MimePart` wich I was able to get the `Stream` of and I placed that stream into another `using (stream stream = part.content.stream)` and used that stream to `stream.CopyTo(file)`

Comment: Did you try calling `attachment.WriteTo` like I suggested?

Comment: honestly I haven't, though I think it would've worked also.. it's because I had 2 options infront of me and I was just going back and forth untill one finally worked. And then I noticed your message.

Comment: a code sample for this would have been awesome, as i am also in need of a solution

Comment: @JasonLokiSmith are you still in need of a solution? I won't make any promises but I might be able to relocate the code I wrote for this

Comment: @fllnAngl, no need thank you. I came across the answer after some more googling. I will post it here after the December holidays. Thank you though